# Check out old versions of files in accurev

Tags: accurev

I need to check out old versions of a bunch of files that were promoted in an issue (I have the number) on December of last year. How do I do this in accurev?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the change package history of this issue.  From that information, you can determine the promote transactions of each file.  Based on the transaction number, you can get the files by perform an "accurev pop -t" or "accurev co -t".